# Выложить газету в AppStore

Tags: appstore

Привет всем!
Я только пытаюсь разобраться в этой теме... Помогите, пожалуйста!
Я редактор детской книжки-газеты, хочу выложить ее в `AppStore`... Просто, чтобы странички ее листались, это вроде не должно быть очень тяжело, она есть у меня в в формате pdf, перевести в другой не проблема.
Как мне это сделать? Через какую программу и в каком формате?
Помогите, пожалуйста, ребята! 
Заранее благодарна.

Comment: Вы хотите просто публикации свои распространять/продавать в аппсторе или сделать аппликацию, которая сможет открывать все газеты, которые вы выпускаете?

Comment: Просто распространять газету в AppStore...

Comment: Если не предполагается брать за это деньги, то я наверное пошел по пути создания аппликации, которая сможет загружать и показывать выпуски газет в newsstand или самостотельно. Потому что если через  newsstand и с использованием каких то готовых сервисов - может быть не бесплатным как минимум!

Comment: Газета будет бесплатная...
Если можно то по-подробнее про аппликацию, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да какие тут подробности? Самый простой вариант - это аппликация с уже загруженными выпусками, когда выходит новый выпуск, обновляется и аппликация с новым выпуском. Можно и более сложные варианты придумать.

Comment: Вы видимо переоцениваете мой уровень. Что такое аппликация, как и в каком формате она делается и как и куда потом заливается, вот что чукче интересно)

Comment: Проще найти программиста, который бы согласился это сделать бесплатно или может договориться с сервисами на бесплатное обслуживание.

Comment: Искала, наверное не там ищу(

Answer (score 2):

Если вы просто хотите загрузить на iPhone/iPad/iPad, загрузите свой PDF на один из облачных сервисов (рекомендую [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) или [Яндекс.Диск](http://disk.yandex.ru/)). Сделайте файл публичным и размещайте ссылки в среде своих читателей - и тогда они смогут загрузить вашу газету к себе на iOs/Android/WinProne... тоже.

Если вы хотите продавать книги на AppStore, то [вот как это делается](http://habrahabr.ru/post/136986/).

Еще один вариант - сотрудничество с имеющимися киосками газет и журналов, навскидку:

- [iNewsStand](http://www.inewsstand.ru/main)
- [PressPoint Reader](http://presspoint.ua/o-proekte/presspoint-reader)
- [Pressa.ru](http://pressa.ru/Rssnews/show/id/1151)

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ.  Я заинтересована именно выкладывать в массы газету. Про  iBookstore поняла, а в формате приложения нельзя ли это сделать? Что бы именно в AppStore?...

Comment: [И это можно](http://www.applifto.ru/article/nachnite-razrabatyvat-ios-prilozheniya-segodnya). Возможно все-таки, что другие способы все-таки окажутся значительно менее трудозатратными.

Answer (score 0):

У вас газета, а с газетами тяжелее. Формат газеты как правило больше по размерам, выходит она чаще и т.п. И понятно, что если для журнала PDF еще сойдет, то для газеты совсем никак.
Для газеты подойдет вот эта система [iPressPad.ru](http://ipresspad.ru).  Эта платформа позволяет выкладывать и газеты и журналы и как PDF и в виде HTML.